# Not a valid origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to replicate a prior project written in pure JS into a React project. This project makes extensive use of the Google API JavaScript Client to access the Youtube Data API, and I'm encountering problems I did not encounter on the original project.

The error I encounter is odd and I shall explain. I have added the following to my api key/ oauth client credentials: `http://localhost:8000`. Actually, this is how it was on the original project - it is unchanged. What is odd now is this error I get:
`"Not a valid origin for the client: http://Localhost:8000 has not been whitelisted for client ID {id}. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."`

I double checked and it is in fact present, but I noticed that the first letter in "local" is uppercased, so I added that specifically. The whitlisted urls are now as follows:

```
http://localhost:8000
http://Localhost:8000
```

After adding that, I get the *same* error again, but missing a *second* L - `http://LocaLhost:8000`.

A few prior searches on stack overflow mentioned clearing browser cache and hard reloading but that has not solved this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the error may actually be?

---

**EDIT**: I've narrowed this down to have something to do with React. If I pull up my old project on my local host it works successfully on the default port for Live Server - 5500. Though if I try to run the React app on my localhost:5500 after closing live server, it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Local host is your development machine, try using your IP address instead. Whitelist your IP address and use the same IP address to check your oauth implementation again

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I used 127.0.0.1 in my browser and I white listed it as well as (attempting) to add my own pc's ip address. Both result in similar issues - that the origin is invalid.

Comment: By IP I didn't mean `127.0.0.1` I meant your actual IP, my bad for not specifying I guess, find out your IP address, it should be something other `127.0.0.1` use that IP address and white list and try the suggestion I gave before

Comment: That was my interpretation - my pc's actual ip address. That didn't work either. Idk if you read my edit but it only happens on React - my original project works fine.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it. I (laughably) included the wrong environment variable. Accidentally included the api key where the oauth client id should've gone.